# Jump to anchor and load src in iframe with one link

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a sort of index at the bottom of an iframed page with 4 different id iframes. I would like to click a link in the index and jump to the iframes position (#TOP) for example then load a html page in the targeted iframe with just one link. How can I do that with JS or something. I have seen snippets that load 2 iframes but I only want to jump to the anchor location THEN load the html resource inside the targeted iframe. I would think there is a simple JS to do that but cant seem to find one. Still learning here so thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#9dd0992a0df7290c6fa8a788924cf274)?

Comment: Thanks ! That IS useful code but I found on another forum the answer which was more simple than I thought. I wanted to just have one link jump to a point on the page where a specific iframe started AND load a new src inside the iframe. The solution that worked was: <a href="pagetoload.html" target="iframeid" onClick="location.href='#THREE'">LOAD PAGE IN THIRD IFRAME</a> works perfect it seems & lightweight. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Good to know you've found a solution! However don't use the onClick attribute though. It's bad practice. Keep your JS in a js file and edit there. Not only is it easier to maintain, but keeps your code clean.